# How do I setup scala IDE for apache-flink?

Tags: eclipse, scala, ide, apache-flink

Im learn apache-flink but not able to setup a scala IDE for it.
I’m using ubuntu 16 os and I have gone through every page in google search. 
Seems like everyone is working on java not scala.
How can i do this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's funny to answer my own question.
IntelliJ seems cumbersome for me so I decided to use traditional eclipse.
So I downloaded scala eclipse from here 
http://scala-ide.org/
then downloaded flink manually from here https://flink.apache.org/downloads.html
Open eclipse and create a project then right click on project then click on properties and go to java build path; then go to libraries tab and click on add External Jars.
Add all the jar files in the flink folder
flink-1.7.0-bin-hadoop28-scala_2.11/flink-1.7.0/opt/
Now you are good to go !

Answer (score 0):

The high-level advice is to use IntelliJ, not Eclipse, for Scala development with Flink. With IntelliJ, install the scala plugin from Jetbrains, and add a Scala SDK in the Global Libraries section of project structure dialog.

I haven't able to get Eclipse to do mixed Java/Scala development.

Comment: can you please guide me to configure intelliJ with flink? The official flink document is out dated.

Comment: Which documentation did you find is out-of-date?